# HAL_Delay fails after flashing code

Tags: stm32, interrupts, reset, hal

My code runs differently if reset vs. power-cycle. My board has a status LED. My program flashes an LED on and off. When I flash my code via my STLink V2 and hit my reset button, the light turns on, indicating the program is running. But stays on, which would mean the code's stuck on the HAL_Delay. If I power-cycle, the code runs fine. The only time a reset does not work is right after flashing. Seems like something about the reset process is wrong, perhaps skipping ISR initialization. I think this because HAL_Delay uses the SysTick_Handler function to increment a counter. And this is the simplest example of a problem I have where my ISRs don't work after programming. But if I do full power cycle they work fine.

Using a STM32L010C6TC.
HSI at 8Mhz, using the PLL to get it up to 32MHz.

- I checked Boot0 pin. It's at 0V when board is powered. Resistance to ground is 10K.
- I checked NRST line. Normally 3.3V. When I press the button it's 0V.
- I'm not using step-through debugging. I just flash via STM32CubeProgrammer.
- I've tried Software reset, Hardware Reset, Core Reset in the STM32CubeProgrammer ST Link configuration menu.
- I've tried setting the nRST_STOP and nRST_STDBY fuse bits HIGH and LOW.

**Update**
Thanks all for the help!
New discovery: I am able to have my code run as I expect following these steps.

1. Connect to STLink plugged into my board, via STM32CubeProgrammer
2. Download .elf to board
3. At this point, a hard reset does not work.
4. Click "disconnect" in STM32CubeProgrammer.
5. Program on board runs as expected.

[image]

**main.c**

```
int main(void)
{
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();

  while (1)
  {
    STATUS_GPIO_Port->ODR |= STATUS_Pin;//LED on
    HAL_Delay(100);//Hangs here after flashing
    STATUS_GPIO_Port->ODR &= ~STATUS_Pin;//LED off
    HAL_Delay(100);
  }
}


void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);
  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIState = RCC_MSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSICalibrationValue = 0;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIClockRange = RCC_MSIRANGE_5;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_MSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  LL_GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  LL_IOP_GRP1_EnableClock(LL_IOP_GRP1_PERIPH_GPIOA);

  /**/
  LL_GPIO_ResetOutputPin(STATUS_GPIO_Port, STATUS_Pin);

  /**/
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = STATUS_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = LL_GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = LL_GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStruct.OutputType = LL_GPIO_OUTPUT_PUSHPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = LL_GPIO_PULL_NO;
  LL_GPIO_Init(STATUS_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}
```

**SysTick_Handler (gen'd by STM32CubeMX)**

```
void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
  HAL_IncTick();
}
```

**HAL_InitTick() (gen'd by STM32CubeMX)**

```
__weak HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_InitTick(uint32_t TickPriority)
{
  /* Configure the SysTick to have interrupt in 1ms time basis*/
  if (HAL_SYSTICK_Config(SystemCoreClock / (1000U / uwTickFreq)) > 0U)
  {
    return HAL_ERROR;
  }

  /* Configure the SysTick IRQ priority */
  if (TickPriority < (1UL << __NVIC_PRIO_BITS))
  {
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, TickPriority, 0U);
    uwTickPrio = TickPriority;
  }
  else
  {
    return HAL_ERROR;
  }

  /* Return function status */
  return HAL_OK;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm. Strange. What if you reset using ST-LINK utility? Working from memory it is something like you click on "Target" then "MCU Core" then there is a reset option. What I am wondering is if your reset HW does not work right for some reason. So try a software reset.

Comment: Oh, also, there may also be some options about what to do after flashing. Maybe the ST-LINK v2 is holding the processor in reset. See if you can find anything like that.

Comment: Make sure the watchdog is disabled / or reseted periodically. It can also be that your board never works, just constantly reset itself making the led flash.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you meant by 'hang'? If you were still in Debug mode after it 'hangs', your code might have reached `HardFault_Handler(void)`. You could try pausing your Debug mode after the code 'hangs' to see where it goes. If your program 'hangs' and went out of Debug mode, your processor might have lost connection with the SWD/ST-Link interface.

Comment: Possibly related issue: https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeF4/issues/113